# How to identify variables that are declared in a function body in clang

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I have implemented a AST resursive visitor with clang and I want to distinguish between variable declarations. I want to know either that a variable declaration is global or if a variable declaration is withing a function body. Both will do the job for me.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit VarDecl in your AST Visiter and then you might wanna use functions like [isLocalVarDecl()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html#ab3fc38243546c278bf42ea0deb0ed8e9), [isLocalVarDeclOrParm()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html#a8cffb3991f9a6f238240d16faae26352), [isFunctionOrMethodVarDecl()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html#a3b5f3ef917987cca85cd9f33f31c567e), [isStaticDataMember()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html#a373bffe9299b1e17054f1bd6c46e00a5), [hasLocalStorage()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html#a86bb48bd6ced47b79a59af7df7108184), or [hasGlobalStorage()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html#a29acc74cf00aaf5d939367f31eeb3aa3) from the VarDecl's Api [here](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html).

Comment: Function hasLocalStorage() can identify variables declared in a local scope. On the other hand function hasGlobalStorage() can identify variables declared on global scope. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That what I thought as well but since I had never used them myself so I added the other potential options as well. Your welcome.